# duplicate mesh along text?

Tags: dupli-groups

Is it possible to duplicate a mesh over text? e.g. in courier new I write Hello, and i want to cover that space in spheres (edit:arbitrary 3D object) without placing each object individually.

I've seen examples of using dupliframes along curves, but is it possible to do it along text?

Edit: I also found out I can convert the text to a curve, but it seems the duplication only follows the outline of the text. Can I do a "fill" with my object? 
[image: getting there...]

Comment: Please convert your text to MESH .... not curve.  Please show an image of your text converted to mesh.  You may have limited images and thus may need to delete older/less valuable images.

Comment: So are you having any improvements or success?  Do you want your meshes to appear all at once or slowly?

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. I think with a googling a few of the commands I'll get to exactly what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A group of particles. Note the outliner windows shows a group of two spheres. 
Press keyboard t to show information panel.  To create a group you may select both spheres and press keyboard Control G. The information panel allows you to type in name.

In the forces you may want  to turn off gravity, gravity = 0.  You may also want to emit all particles quickly.  Start = 1. End = 2.

[image]
Single Object Particle

[image]

Convert the text to mesh and use particles. Note the vertices of the mesh in edit mode are highlighted. The particle object will be a sphere.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the reply but i should have been more generic. what if i want it to be any random 3D mesh?

Comment: Group example added.